# Custom slider throwing an error

Tags: errors, theme-customizer, slideshow

Hi am using Customised slider in my theme from another theme

I add this code in my customizer.php

```
function mytheme_customize_register( $wp_customize ) {

    //Slider
    $wp_customize->add_section( 'advance_business_slider' , array(
        'title'      => __( 'Slider Settings', 'mytheme' ),
        'priority'   => null,
        'panel' => 'advance_business_panel_id'
    ) );

    $wp_customize->add_setting('advance_business_slider_hide',array(
       'default' => 'false',
       'sanitize_callback'  => 'sanitize_text_field'
    ));
    $wp_customize->add_control('advance_business_slider_hide',array(
       'type' => 'checkbox',
       'label' => __('Show / Hide slider','mytheme'),
       'section' => 'advance_business_slider',
    ));

    for ( $count = 1; $count <= 4; $count++ ) {

        // Add color scheme setting and control.
        $wp_customize->add_setting( 'advance_business_slider_page' . $count, array(
            'default'           => '',
            'sanitize_callback' => 'advance_business_sanitize_dropdown_pages'
        ) );

        $wp_customize->add_control( 'advance_business_slider_page' . $count, array(
            'label'    => __( 'Select Slide Image Page', 'mytheme' ),
            'section'  => 'advance_business_slider',
            'type'     => 'dropdown-pages'
        ) );
    }


}
add_action( 'customize_register', 'mytheme_customize_register' );
```

It gives option in my theme custom menu when I add slider using this it give me an error

> Unable to save due to 1 invalid setting.

I cant find solution for this error. Any help would be highly appreciated.